# FuelUX has no data parameter for the changed event?

Tags: fuelux

Is it by design that the changed event does not pass a data parameter into the function?

```
$('#MyWizard').on('changed', function(e, data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
```

The above shows the data as being undefined.

**Update**

I suppose I can get around the issue by use this:

$('#MyWizard').on('changed', function(e, data) {
                var item = $('#MyWizard').wizard('selectedItem');
            });

Comment: and then you can use item.step to get current step. great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated in my update I used this:

```
$('#MyWizard').on('changed', function(e, data) { var item = $('#MyWizard').wizard('selectedItem'); });
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else using FuelUX 2.6.1 (or another close version), this question helped me hook into the `changed` event for `datepicker`:

```
$(function() {
    $('#idOfDatePicker').datepicker({
        date : new Date(),
        createInput : false,
        dropdownWidth : 170,
        restrictDateSelection : true
    }).on('changed', function(event, date) {
        //Useful code goes here!
    });
});
```